# Do Hidden Smart Groups get 'calculated' when we click on Smart Groups on a Contact's 'Group' tab?

Tags: smartgroups

Does anyone know if Hidden Groups are checked or ignored when a COUNT of contacts in a Smart Group is run, or when you click on Smart Groups on a Contact's Groups tag?

Am looking in to why clicking on Smart Groups on a Contact's Groups tag is so slow and the site in question has a lot of Hidden Groups due to sending mail from a Search Result.